# parse.com getting current user in to textfields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, parse-platform

I have my current user output to `NSLog` as follows

```
adress1 = "result"
address2 = "result"
address3 = "result"
postcode = "result"
displayname = "result"
email = "result"
mobile = "result"
```

Now I have those details. How do I get them to appear in my view controller using `textfield` as I want the user to be able to change and edit the details if needed

my .h file

```
@interface UserEditViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *UserNameText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *EmailAddressText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *MobileText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Address1Text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *Address2Text;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *PostCodeText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *TaxiOrCust;


- (IBAction)SaveBtn:(id)sender;
```

I have tried

```
UserNameText = displayname
```

but can't seem to bring up the display name

I have posted in parse and to tell the truth there forums are rubbish as no one replays for days.

Comment: you want to show data comes from parse to uitextfield or wht?

Comment: if u want user to make change and edit details of a textfield, then set userIntractionEnable to yes

Comment: yes i want to show the data from current user and put it in to the uitextfields. then give the user option to edit if needed

Comment: How are you retrieving displayname? Did you see its value using NSLog? And you should use the text property of UItextField, otherwise your code will crash.

Comment: theres no reference to userIntractionEnable in apple's documentation help

Comment: yes i get the NSLOG output showing details of the data output as above

Comment: @MikeAsp, Please follow the below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer the comments below :-

1)Well first thing you need to check. Whether you have connected proper `bindings` with your `textfield`.

2) Second thing, if bindings are proper then check inside Interface Builder -> `Attribute inspector->View->interaction should be enabled`

3)Now for setting the textvalue inside textfield **@A Bao** has mentioned follow that. Though, you have taken the property of `textfield`. So modify the code like that using self  `self.UserNameText.Text = displayname;` and also make sure displayname should not contain nil value.

```
NSString *displayName = [currentUser objectForKey:@"displayName"];

self.UserNameText.Text = displayName;
```

Comment: im a bit embarrassed but I'm new to iOS dev and not sure what you mean by have connected proper bindings with your textfield. i have linked them to my .hfile and the show up if i start to type there name in my .m file

Comment: It means you have not define display name in your code?? Did you define in your code somewhere like NSString *displayname=@"test"??

Comment: NSString *displayname=  @"displayname";
    
     self.UserNameText.text = display name;        this just fetches up the word displayname its not looking in to the data from currentuser

Comment: @MikeAsp, Not clear what you are asking. Whatever string you set in the textfield it will set that value only. So if you execute the code like that NSString *displayname= @"displayname"; self.UserNameText.text = displayname; Definietly it will set the textvalue displayname only

Comment: i really do understand what you are saying but do you understand i am working with Parse.com database. and there needs to be some sort off query of the database which was    [[PFUser currentUser] refresh];
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser]; ...... currentuser holds the data that NSLog has output ...... so displayname= @"displayname";  should be something like displayname= forKey @"display name"; or objectforkey but none work.

Comment: I agree your point, But whatever value you will get from database. You can store into some string variable if its coming in the string and set the same into textfield accordingly??

Comment: but its not i am trying  displayname= forKey @"display name"; or objectforkey but none work. i know the data is in there but i just can't get it out to the screen

Comment: solved it thanks to you and one more post we was both right answer in edit above

Answer (score 0):

Do it as -

```
 UserNameText.Text = displayname;
```

Comment: that dosnt work there some sort of pfquery needed but not sure what once i have my data in NSlog i can't seem to display it